# Scipy install help windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, scipy

I am trying to get `scipy` running on my computer and I have been fighting for the last few hours with it. Currently, im running python 3.6 and I am on windows 10. I first tried to install it using `pip` which failed no matter what I did. Then I went and downloaded the wheel file and installed it manually using `pip`. Then I used `pip` to get the rest of the dependencies like the website stated `pip install --user numpy scipy matplotlib ipython jupyter pandas sympy nose`. It installed the rest of the packages just fine. 
If I say in `IDEL`

```
import scipy
```

It will give me an error of

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    from scipy import special, optimize
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\__init__.py", line 116, in <module>
    from scipy._lib._ccallback import LowLevelCallable
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\_lib\_ccallback.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import _ccallback_c
ImportError: cannot import name '_ccallback_c'
```

if I go in that file to comment out that line, it will import but it after that I get a lot more errors anytime I try and do anything.

Also, I tried installing `anaconda` as a dependency manager and that seemed to work fine for installing, but if I tried to used `Atom` or `IDLE` as my text editor it can't seem to find scipy when its compiling and throws and error. I am kinda at a loss and any advice or help on this would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Install anaconda (the full batteries included version not `miniconda`) from the continuum io binary. It comes by default with spyder.

Comment: Using anaconda is a good call. When installed, scipy and co is available and the only thing in the way is to use the correct binaries. You did not show how you call your scripts and you are probably are still using old paths / old non-anaconda python. Just edit your system-environment path-variables (or call anaconda/bin/python directly).

Comment: I did that and it seems to be working. Thank you for your help!